# How does 'ask something of somebody' mean 'to expect or demand something'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was reading [Meaning of “ask of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/38174/50720) when I lighted upon this issue:

> This meaning of [ask](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/ask) (definition 7) is mentioned in the OALD:
>
> 7. **ask something of somebody** =
> [transitive] to expect or demand something ...

Question 1. I ask not about the definition which I tolerate, but about how to decompose/derive/parse   it?
How does the juxtaposition of **ask** and **of** effect/imply/induce definition 7?

**Update 2014 Jan 17:** I wrongly guessed [ODO's Definition 3](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of) as the definition of **of** here. Proof removed.

Comment: *Of* in this idiom does not have the sense of possession but the sense of deriving *from* something: the same sense it has, for instance, in names like *John of Gaunt* or in  *of good family* or *the advantage of such-and-such*.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [phrasal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb).  Quoted from Wikipedia, (primary source cited from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Phrasal_verb&oldid=648064412#cite_note-1)):

> This semantic unit cannot be understood based upon the meanings of the individual parts in isolation, but rather it can be taken as a whole. In other words, the meaning is non-compositional and thus unpredictable.

One must learn the definition of phrasal verbs like one would learn the definition of single words.  There are guides that help group them in various ways, but there are lots of exceptions as well.

Answer (score 0):

The word "of" used to mean "from".  It's sometimes still used in that sense.

Thus, the phrase "ask something of somebody" really means "ask [for] something *from* somebody".